# In Windows 7 identify ip of a mapped drive and reconnect it

Tags: parsing, windows-7, command-prompt, windows-7-x64, network-drive

I know that I can show mapped drives in windows 7 using

`c:\>net use`

and it shows

```
Status       Local     Remote                    Network
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
OK           X:        \\192.168.168.100\c\Output
                                            Microsoft Windows Network
OK           Y:        \\192.168.168.100\c\Input
                                            Microsoft Windows Network
```

Is it possible to discover if X (or Y) are connected to ip 192.168.168.100 ?
And in this case disconnect them using

```
net use X: /delete
net use Y: /delete
```

and reconnect them to same path but different ip using (from 192.168.168.100 to 192.168.168.101)

```
net use X: \\192.168.168.101\c\Output /user:user01
net use Y: \\192.168.168.101\c\Input  /user:user01
```

and viceversa, if they are connected to 192.168.168.101, disconnect and reconnect
to 192.168.168.100

Can someone help me to parse the net use output ?

Comment: It looks like you figured it out. What specifically do you need help with?

Comment: I don't know how to identify, within a .bat, if the mapped drive refers to 192.168.168.100 or 192.168.168.101 and then act accordingly

Comment: As you saw, you can use the `net use` command and parse the output.

Comment: Can someone help me to parse the net use output ?

Comment: You can use the `for` command to parse the output of a command. Type `for /?` for details.

Answer (score 0):

Not pretty but it works in my limited testing:

```
@echo OFF
setlocal ENABLEEXTENSIONS DISABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
goto start

:checkone
setlocal
echo INFO: %3 is mapped to drive %2
set "server="&set "new="
for /F "usebackq tokens=1,* delims=\" %%A in ('%3') do @set server=%%A&set share=%%B
if "%server%"=="192.168.168.100" set new=192.168.168.101
if "%server%"=="192.168.168.101" set new=192.168.168.100
if not ".%new%"=="." (
    call net use %2 /delete
    call net use %2 \\%new%\%share% /user:user01
)
endlocal
@goto :EOF

:start
for /F "tokens=*" %%A in ('net use^|find ":"^|find "\\"') do @for /F "usebackq tokens=1,* delims=:" %%B in ('.%%A') do call :checkone %%B: %%C
```

If the remote path has spaces there will probably be trouble...